# On Mac and on Raspi same error: EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:9092

Tags: apache-kafka, websocket, raspberry-pi

### What happened:

I am running kafka and zookeeper with the docker-compose.yml below on my local machine. With server.js I was always able to run a node websocket server to transmit messages.

Also I am connected to a raspi 4 via ssh. The raspi is in the same network like my machine and also runs kafka and zookeeper.

Somehow I now get an error message (seen below) if I run the server.js. I tried running the script on both, the raspi and my macbook, and I alway get the same message.

### I tried the following

- I searched for other processes using this port and I only found the docker container using it.

  (base) ➜  server git:(branch_julian) ✗ lsof -i:9092
  COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
  com.docke 7145 jumue   74u  IPv6 0x4d78cd0e1c9333df      0t0  TCP *:XmlIpcRegSvc (LISTEN)
- I already restarted docker.
- Closed the ssh connection to the pi

### Scripts running

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
        container_name: 'zookeeper'
        ports:
        - '2181:2181'
        environment:
        - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    kafka:
        image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
        container_name: 'kafka'
        ports:
        - '9092:9092'
        environment:
        - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
        - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
        - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
        - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
        - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
        depends_on:
        - zookeeper
```

server.js

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
var Kafka = require('no-kafka');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: "9092" });

wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("Kafka is connected");

    // Create an instance of the Kafka consumer
    const consumer = new Kafka.SimpleConsumer;
    var data = function (messageSet, topic, partition) {
        messageSet.forEach(function (m) {
            console.log(topic, partition, m.offset, m.message.value.toString('utf8'));
            ws.send(m.message.value.toString('utf8'))
        });
    };

    ws.on("close", () => {
        console.log("Client has disconnected");
    });

    // Subscribe to the Kafka topic
    return consumer.init().then(function () {
        return consumer.subscribe('test', data);
    });
});
```

### Error Message

```
(base) ➜  websocketserver git:(branch_me) ✗ node server/server.js         
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:9092
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1314:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1362:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1499:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocketServer instance at:
    at Server.WebSocketServer._onServerError (/Users/jumue/virtual7/tasks/0006_lui_dashboard/websocketserver/server/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:82:50)
    at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1341:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -48,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 9092
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `server.js` code, you are trying to create a WebSocket server on the port 9092 which is already allocated by Kafka already.

You should better [check npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-kafka#simpleconsumer) or [github documentation](https://github.com/oleksiyk/kafka). You may configure your Kafka to another port and configure your SimpleConsumer (using `connectionString`) accordingly.